# get text from tkinter text box in a different function

Tags: python, function, tkinter, get, textbox

Good Day.
I have a simple tkinter UI with 4 checkbuttons.  Each has an associated text box.  I have managed to create the UI by getting the checkbox state and the text in the textbox from a dictionary in a .txt file.  I can also write the changed checkbutton state back to the file successfully with the update() function.

PROBLEM:  I am having trouble figuring out how to get and write the changed text in the textbox back to the file.  I need to get the textbox string for each textbox, but they are local to the makeUI() function.  I am not sure how to pass all the textboxes to the update() function.

Suggestions on how to solve this would be most gratefully appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import json

def loadDictFile(data_folder): 
    critDict = json.loads(open(data_folder+'critDict3.txt').read())
    return critDict

def update(critDict, checkbuttons, data_folder):
    for k in checkbuttons:
        key = k.cget('text')
        critDict[key][0] = k.var.get() 
        critDict[key][1] = commentBox.get("1.0",'end-1c') # <--HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    with open(data_folder+'critDict3.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(critDict))

def makeUI(data_folder, critDict):
    newDict = critDict
    top = Tk()
    checkbuttons={}
    for key, val in newDict.items():
        chkVar = IntVar()
        key  = Checkbutton(top, text = key, variable=chkVar) 
        key.var = chkVar
        key.var.set(val[0])
        key.pack()

        commentBox = ScrolledText(top, height=2, width=30)
        commentBox.pack()
        commentBox.insert(END, val[1])
        comment = commentBox.get("1.0",'end-1c')
        checkbuttons[key]=comment

    print('checkbuttons is', checkbuttons)

    button=Button(top, text="Update", command=lambda : update(critDict, checkbuttons, data_folder))
    button.pack()

    top.mainloop()


data_folder = "C:\\Users\\NB\\test\\data\\"
critDict = loadDictFile(data_folder)
makeUI(data_folder, critDict)
```

and here is the text of the disk file 'critDict3.txt

```
{
"crit1": [1, "comments"], "crit4": [1, "comment4"], "crit2": [1, "comment2"], "crit3": [1, "comments3"]
}
```

Comment: do the same as with Checkbuttons - create list/dictionary with all `commentBox` and send to `update` as argument - `update(...,  all_textboxes)` - and inside `update()` use ie. `all_textboxes[0].get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create list/dictionary with all `chkVar` and `commentBox`

```
 all_items[key] = [chkVar, commentBox]
```

and sent to `update()`

```
 command=lambda:update(critDict, all_items, data_folder))
```

and inside `update()` you can access it

```
 for key, [chkVar, commentBox]  in all_items.items():
```

---

```
def makeUI(data_folder, critDict):
    top = Tk()

    all_items = {}

    for key, val in critDict.items():
        chkVar = IntVar(value=val[0])
        cb = Checkbutton(top, text=key, variable=chkVar) 
        cb.pack()

        commentBox = ScrolledText(top, height=2, width=30)
        commentBox.pack()
        commentBox.insert('end', val[1])

        all_items[key] = [chkVar, commentBox]

    button = Button(top, text="Update", command=lambda:update(critDict, all_items, data_folder))
    button.pack()

    top.mainloop()

def update(critDict, all_items, data_folder):

    for key, [chkVar, commentBox]  in all_items.items():
        critDict[key] = [chkVar.get(), commentBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c')]

    with open(data_folder+'critDict3.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(critDict))
```

Comment: Thank you @furas, I have added the changes and this almost works.  I receive an error that the keys must be a string:, when I convert the keys to a string: all_items[str(key)] = [chkVar, commentBox] then I get new items appended to the dictionary rather than overwriting the old values.  Thoughts?

Comment: here is part of the error message: Exception in Tkinter callback

    return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: keys must be a string

Comment: I think I have found the problem(not the solution).  The dict file in this format: {'crit1': [1, 'comments'], 'crit3': [1, 'comments3'], 'crit4': [1, 'comment4'], 'crit2': [1, 'comment2']}  but when I  json.dumps the file, it looks like this: {<tkinter.Checkbutton object .1953698217264>: [1, 'comments'], 'crit2': [1, 'comment2'], 'crit3': [1, 'comments3'], <tkinter.Checkbutton object .1953698347888>: [1, 'comment4'], 'crit1': [1, 'comments'], <tkinter.Checkbutton object .1953698347440>: [1, 'comments3'], 'crit4': [1, 'comment4'], <tkinter.Checkbutton object .1953698348336>: [1, 'comment2']}

Comment: So the issue seems to be that the critDict[key] made in the update() function is the tkinter object ID, instead of the key from when we load the critDict, which should be 'crit1', 'crit2', 'crit3', or 'crit4'.

Comment: SOLVED:  I was overwriting my critDict key when I created the check buttons.